# Determine whether a function is the squared gradient of a harmonic function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, harmonic-functions, laplacian, potential-theory

Today I learned that, if $w$ (a real function defined on a region of $\mathbb R^n$) is a harmonic function, then $U:=\left|\nabla u\right|^2$ is subharmonic.
This result makes me wonder whether there is a condition that is sufficient for $U$ to be written in that form.

In other words, given a real function $U$ defined on some region of $\mathbb R^n$, how can we determine whether there exists (at least locally)
a harmonic function $u$ such that $U=\left|\nabla u\right|^2$?